# Maximum size for an entity 1,048,572 bytes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can see that where I have to face `Maximum size for an entity` limit mentioned this doc [**Limits**](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits). Could you tell me what they mean here `an entity`? Is that `projects`(this is the entity which it shows the above error) `with collections` or `without collections`? How can I avoid this issue? I'm using `firestore`.

This is my data structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity in this case refers to a single document, excluding any sub-collections that might exist under that document.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much :)